# How does one find the menu path to an administrative option given a text string?

Tags: administrator

When encountering a problem, search engines will often return plethora of hits of people encountering a similar problem.  These usually point to support fora in which solutions are offered in terms of some administrative action to take.  However, the description of the administrative action is rarely in the form of the complete menu path to the administrative option.  For example, rather than saying:

`Content > Categories > Uncategorized > Options > Layout > From Component > Blog`

The solution will be offered in terms like:

`Select the layout from component blog.`

While it is frequently feasible to figure out the former from the latter, it can in many cases be quite time consuming.  Is there anything in Joomla -- or an administrative plugin or extension -- that can assist in searching the menu text strings to locate the menu path?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of any plugin or extension that can help with this and as far as I know, there is no "Search" or similar feature in the back-end.

I can understand the need for something like this as some features are certainly not easy to find for a novice or experienced user e.g. the new router settings.

Ideally when explaining administrative actions, authors should make it clear how to navigate through the menu path to reach the relevant feature as you have shown in your question. Where this is not done, and it's not clear or simple to find the relevant feature, the best course of action is probably to ask the author to explain the menu path more clearly.

Even when authors sufficiently explain the menu path, it's unfortunate that the menu structure varies between Joomla versions and even since Joomla 3 was released, the menu options and structure have been simplified.

When asking a question, it can help to specify which Joomla version you are using so the answer can include the appropriate administration menu paths.